# Difference between Introduce Parameter and Change Method signature in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, parameters

Difference between Introduce Parameter and Change Method signature in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce parameter lets you convert a local expression to a parameter of the current method that will be added to the end of the parameter's list.

Change method signature allows you to introduce parameters *without any special relation* to your method's body, reorder or modify existing parameters.

A good overview can be found in Eclipse's help

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-menu-refactor.htm (Galileo)

respectively

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-menu-refactor.htm (Helios)

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking of the Introduce parameter Object refactoring, one answer can be found here:

http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html

In fact this creates a new class representing your parameters where as the Change method signature allows to change method return type, visibility and parameters.

If you are speaking about the introduce parameter when a field or local variable is **selected**, this will just add a new parameter to the enclosing method with the same name and the same type than the selected field or local variable and thus use this parameter instead.

Manu